# problem combining values in arraylists java

Tags: java, arraylist

i'm trying to combine all possible combinations of the strings i have in the iceCream and toppings string lists. But this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IceCream {
    public long printMenu( ) {
        int scoops[] = {0, 1};
        String iceCream[] = {" ", "chocolate", "vanilla", "strawberry"};
        String toppings[] = {" ", "sprinkles", "whipped cream", "chocolate chips"};
        ArrayList<String> menuList = new ArrayList<String>();
        long menu_num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < scoops.length; i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < iceCream.length; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < toppings.length; y++) {
                    menu_num++;
                    if (i == 0) {
                        menuList.add(toppings[y]);
                    }
                    if (i == 1) {
                        if (toppings[y] == toppings[0]) {
                            menuList.add(iceCream[x]);
                        }
                        else {
                            menuList.add(iceCream[x] + toppings[y]);
                        }
                    }
                        System.out.println(menuList);
                    }
                }

            }
            return menu_num;
        }

    public static void main( String [ ] args ) {
        IceCream obj = new IceCream( );
        long count = obj.printMenu( );
        assert count == 32;
    }
}
```

outputs

```
[ ]
[ , sprinkles]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ,  sprinkles]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ,  sprinkles,  whipped cream]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ,  sprinkles,  whipped cream,  chocolate chips]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ,  sprinkles,  whipped cream,  chocolate chips, chocolate]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ,  sprinkles,  whipped cream,  chocolate chips, chocolate, chocolatesprinkles]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ,  sprinkles,  whipped cream,  chocolate chips, chocolate, chocolatesprinkles, chocolatewhipped cream]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ,  sprinkles,  whipped cream,  chocolate chips, chocolate, chocolatesprinkles, chocolatewhipped cream, chocolatechocolate chips]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ,  sprinkles,  whipped cream,  chocolate chips, chocolate, chocolatesprinkles, chocolatewhipped cream, chocolatechocolate chips, vanilla]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ,  sprinkles,  whipped cream,  chocolate chips, chocolate, chocolatesprinkles, chocolatewhipped cream, chocolatechocolate chips, vanilla, vanillasprinkles]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ,  sprinkles,  whipped cream,  chocolate chips, chocolate, chocolatesprinkles, chocolatewhipped cream, chocolatechocolate chips, vanilla, vanillasprinkles, vanillawhipped cream]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ,  sprinkles,  whipped cream,  chocolate chips, chocolate, chocolatesprinkles, chocolatewhipped cream, chocolatechocolate chips, vanilla, vanillasprinkles, vanillawhipped cream, vanillachocolate chips]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ,  sprinkles,  whipped cream,  chocolate chips, chocolate, chocolatesprinkles, chocolatewhipped cream, chocolatechocolate chips, vanilla, vanillasprinkles, vanillawhipped cream, vanillachocolate chips, strawberry]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ,  sprinkles,  whipped cream,  chocolate chips, chocolate, chocolatesprinkles, chocolatewhipped cream, chocolatechocolate chips, vanilla, vanillasprinkles, vanillawhipped cream, vanillachocolate chips, strawberry, strawberrysprinkles]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ,  sprinkles,  whipped cream,  chocolate chips, chocolate, chocolatesprinkles, chocolatewhipped cream, chocolatechocolate chips, vanilla, vanillasprinkles, vanillawhipped cream, vanillachocolate chips, strawberry, strawberrysprinkles, strawberrywhipped cream]
[ , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  , sprinkles, whipped cream, chocolate chips,  ,  sprinkles,  whipped cream,  chocolate chips, chocolate, chocolatesprinkles, chocolatewhipped cream, chocolatechocolate chips, vanilla, vanillasprinkles, vanillawhipped cream, vanillachocolate chips, strawberry, strawberrysprinkles, strawberrywhipped cream, strawberrychocolate chips]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

i can't figure out why it's printing the toppings over and over again and i just want a list with all combos of the flavors and toppings. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IceCream {

public long printMenu( ) 
{
    int scoops[] = {0, 1};
    String iceCream[] = {" ", "chocolate", "vanilla", "strawberry"};
    String toppings[] = {" ", "sprinkles", "whipped cream", "chocolate chips"};

    ArrayList<String> menuList = new ArrayList<String>();
    long menu_num = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < iceCream.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < toppings.length; y++)
        {
            menu_num++;
            menuList.add(iceCream[x] + " " +  toppings[y]);
        }
    }

        System.out.println(menuList);
        return menu_num;
    }

public static void main( String [ ] args ) {
    IceCream obj = new IceCream( );
    long count = obj.printMenu( );
        System.out.println(count);
    //assert count == 32;
}
```

}

Comment: how can you make it so you can have multiple toppings with each flavor?